# Flutter localizations for different flavors

Tags: flutter

What are the best practices for having a different localization based on the flavor?

For example: let's say we have musicians flavor and a painters flavor, the app has the same UI for both, only the texts should change, how can this be done?

I tried searching through the official documentation, but i couldn't find anything that could help

Comment: can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: I cannot start if i don't know how to do it